# How to end CSS transition with jquery or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

I want to end my css transition with jquery or js. I don't mean pause, I want to end them, as if they became 100% done. I have css transitions and not animations.

The properties I am using transition on are top and left, and it is a position absolute element.

Comment: Share your code, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply override the transition-property rule to `none`.

```css
#el {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 5s linear;
  background: red;
}
body:hover #el{
  left: calc(100vw - 50px);
}
button:active + #el {
  transition-property: none;
}
:root,body{margin:0}
```

```html
<button>stop transition</button>
<div id="el"></div>
```

Now how you trigger this is up to you, it can be using a special class, or any other condition.

Answer (score 0):

Hello your question is kinda ambiguous.

if you are using transition instead of animation you can control the flow of it in the same css example :

```
   transition: background-color .2s linear 0s; /*Standard*/
```

If you want to interrupt the transition with JS you can assign other Css valor to an different class name or property when some action you want is triggered.

```
       .normal{
        transition: background-color .2s linear 0s; /*Standard*/ 
        }  

         [stop = yes] {
          background: black; 
          } 

        document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(someting you want){
          document.queryselector(".normal").setAttribute("stop","yes");
         }
     else{
       document.queryselector(".normal").setAttribute("stop","no");
      }
     },false);
```

if something you want were triggered then the atribute will be set to the no 
 transition and this also cut off the running one.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.toggle-animation').click(function(){
  $('.element').stop(true).toggleClass('animating');
});
```

```css
.element{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    background: red
}
.animating{
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;;
    transition: all 5s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
<button type="button" class="toggle-animation">Click me</button>
```

Comment: uh im pretty sure u posted the exact same code twice on accident